# Expose variable from c++ to qml

Tags: c++, qt, qml, c++17

```
class Program
{
public:
    Program() = delete;
    Program(const QString &n, const QString &ip);
    Program(const Program &other) = delete;
    Program(Program &&other) = default;
    ~Program() = default;

    Program &operator=(const Program &other) = delete;
    Program &operator=(const Program &&other) = delete;

    constexpr static size_t maxProgram = 99;

private:
    QString name;
    QString imagePath;
};
```

Hi, I want expose my variable `maxProgram` from this class to QML, I think thant in the following code its work but I appreciate other clean solution.

```
enum def {
    foo = maxProgram
};
Q_ENUM(def)
```

Comment: So you've tried it and it works?

Comment: @Mitch no but with other normal enum's class works...

Answer (score 1):

Use Q_PROPERTY with the CONSTANT attribute:

```
Q_PROPERTY(int maxProgram READ getMaxProgram CONSTANT)
```

...

```
private:
    int getMaxProgram() const {
        return maxProgram;
    }
```

size_t won't work, but since 5.10 you can use qsizetype

Answer (score 1):

Qt have a good documentation search them first instead of posting a question.[OverAll description Page](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qtqml-cppintegration-overview.html) and specific [Answer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qtqml-cppintegration-contextproperties.html).

C++

```
class ApplicationData : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT
 public:
   Q_INVOKABLE QDateTime getCurrentDateTime() const {
    return QDateTime::currentDateTime();
   }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

  QQuickView view;

  ApplicationData data;
  view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("applicationData", &data);

  view.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("MyItem.qml"));
  view.show();

  return app.exec();
}
```

QML

```
// MyItem.qml
import QtQuick 2.0

Text { text: applicationData.getCurrentDateTime() }
```