# How to send a variable from c++ to qml? Can you send me an exampe

Tags: qt

How to send a variable from c++ to qml? Can you send me an exampe.

Comment: Did you try searching at all? Why didn't the results help? What kind of variable are you trying to send, and when? This is very unclear and lacking in evidence of research/effort.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing parameters from C++ to QML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45716708/passing-parameters-from-c-to-qml) or [Expose variable from c++ to qml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51286723/expose-variable-from-c-to-qml) or etc., etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [something like this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-topic.html)

look at `backend.userName`

```
TextField {
    text: backend.userName
    placeholderText: qsTr("User name")
    anchors.centerIn: parent

    onTextChanged: backend.userName = text
}
```